# jquery json can each be used to do something like each where title='mytitle'

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

```
            $.each(udt.Data, function(i, Data) {
                $("#output").append("<h4>" + Data.productTitle + "</h4>");
            });
```

I have the above code to loop through a json result what would be the best way to do something like  for each Data where productTitle   = 'product1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep)

```
var arr = $.grep(udt.Data, function(Data, i){
  return Data.productTitle === 'product1';
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/BBsK3/2/)**